# Making row values into column values -- SQL PIVOT

Tags: sql, pivot

SQL Returns the following results from table: CowTracking

```
    ID  cow_id  barn_id
    --  ------  -------
    19    5       3
    20    5       2
    21    5       9
    22    5       1
```

I am trying to get the following results with a PIVOT in SQL

```
     cow_id  barn1  barn2  barn3  barn4
     ------  -----  -----  -----  -----
       5       3      2      9      1
```

This is the code I have so far.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP 4 *
        FROM CowTracking
            WHERE cow_id = 5
    ) AS DataTable
    PIVOT
    (
        MIN(barn_id) **IDK what function to use and which column to use it on**
        FOR ID  ??<---**NOT SURE**
        IN 
        (
        [barn1], [barn2], [barn3], [barn4]
        )
    ) AS PivotTable


    ERRORS: Error converting data type nvarchar to int
            The incorrect value "barn1" is supplied in the PIVOT operator
```

NOTE: The barn_id is a varchar. It will not be possible to change the datatype.

I am not trying to add/multiply/aggregate or whatever. I am simply trying to move the row to a column

How would I go about doing this?
Is this the correct thought process?

Do I even need to use PIVOT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As there is no `barn1..4` in your tables, you somehow have to replace the `ID`'s with their corresponding `barn`s.

One solution using `PIVOT` might be like this

```
SELECT  cow_id
        , [19] as [barn1]
        , [20] as [barn2]
        , [21] as [barn3]
        , [22] as [barn4]
FROM    (       
            SELECT  *
            FROM    DataTable
            PIVOT   (   MIN(barn_id)
                        FOR ID IN ([19], [20], [21], [22])
                    ) AS PivotTable
        ) q
```

another solution using `CASE` and `GROUP BY` could be

```
SELECT  cow_id
        , [barn1] = SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 19 THEN barn_id END)
        , [barn2] = SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 20 THEN barn_id END)
        , [barn3] = SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 21 THEN barn_id END)
        , [barn4] = SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 22 THEN barn_id END)
FROM    DataTable
GROUP BY
        cow_id
```

but in essence, this all boils down to hardcoding an `ID` to a `barn`.

---

**Edit**

If you always return a fixed number of records, and using SQL Server you might make this a bit more robust by

- adding a `ROW_NUMBER` to each result
- pivot on this upfront known number

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  cow_id  
        , [barn1] = SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN barn_id END)
        , [barn2] = SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN barn_id END)
        , [barn3] = SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN barn_id END)
        , [barn4] = SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN barn_id END)
FROM    (
            SELECT  cow_id
                    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
                    , barn_id
            FROM    DataTable       
        ) q
GROUP BY
        cow_id
```

**Test script**

```
;WITH DataTable (ID, cow_id, barn_id) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        (19, 5, 3)
        , (20, 5, 2)
        , (21, 5, 9)
        , (22, 5, 1)
    ) AS q (a, b, c)        
)
SELECT  cow_id  
        , [barn1] = SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN barn_id END)
        , [barn2] = SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN barn_id END)
        , [barn3] = SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN barn_id END)
        , [barn4] = SUM(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN barn_id END)
FROM    (
            SELECT  cow_id
                    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
                    , barn_id
            FROM    DataTable       
        ) q
GROUP BY
        cow_id
```

Comment: your first suggestion is spot on. at first i was worried because the ID would always change. but then i declared a new column and had it set so that it would always be 1 - 4. then i was able to accomplish it. thanks mate, much appreciated. took me a little bit to get my head around this concept