# Pivot 3 rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Quote and I want to get the last 3 notes for that quote into a single row. By Selecting the top 3 from quotes I have a QuoteNote table:

```
QuoteNoteID       QuoteID      Note        NoteAreaID
     1               1         Test            2
     2               1         Test2           1
     3               1         Test3           1
```

I have a select on this table which brings me back the information I need

```
SELECT q.QuoteNoteID, q.QuoteID, q.Note, q.NoteAreaID, n.Description AS NoteAreaDesc
FROM Quote q INNER JOIN QuoteNote n ON n.QuoteID = q.QuoteID
```

This gives me

```
QuoteNoteID       QuoteID      Note        NoteAreaID        NoteAreaDesc
     1               1         Test            2               Internal
     2               1         Test2           1               External
     3               1         Test3           1               External
```

Now All I want to do is put this into one row

```
QuoteID    Note1    Note2    Note3    NoteAreaID1     NoteAreaID2    NoteAreaID3    NoteAreaDesc1    NoteAreaDesc2      NoteAreaDesc3
  1         Test     Test2   Tes3         2                1              1           Internal            External       External
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Hope this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117955/making-row-values-into-column-values-sql-pivot

Comment: @Kaf Thanks for the suggestion but the pivot only works for a single column, I need a multiple column solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
WITH QuoteNotes AS
(   SELECT  QuoteNote.QuoteNoteID, 
            Quote.QuoteID, 
            QuoteNote.Note, 
            QuoteNote.NoteAreaID, 
            [NoteAreaDesc] = QuoteNote.Description,
            [QuoteNoteNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Quote.QuoteID ORDER BY QuoteNote.QuoteNoteID)
    FROM    Quote
            INNER JOIN QuoteNote
                ON QuoteNote.QuoteID = Quote.QuoteID
)
SELECT  QuoteID,
        [Note1] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuoteNoteNumber = 1 THEN Note END),
        [Note2] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuoteNoteNumber = 2 THEN Note END),
        [Note3] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuoteNoteNumber = 3 THEN Note END),
        [NoteAreaID1] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuoteNoteNumber = 1 THEN NoteAreaID END),
        [NoteAreaID2] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuoteNoteNumber = 2 THEN NoteAreaID END),
        [NoteAreaID3] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuoteNoteNumber = 3 THEN NoteAreaID END),
        [NoteAreaDesc1] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuoteNoteNumber = 1 THEN NoteAreaDesc END),
        [NoteAreaDesc2] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuoteNoteNumber = 2 THEN NoteAreaDesc END),
        [NoteAreaDesc3] = MAX(CASE WHEN QuoteNoteNumber = 3 THEN NoteAreaDesc END)
FROM    QuoteNotes
GROUP BY QuoteID;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/177a7/3)**

Or

```
WITH QuoteNotes AS
(   SELECT  QuoteNote.QuoteNoteID, 
            Quote.QuoteID, 
            QuoteNote.Note, 
            QuoteNote.NoteAreaID, 
            [NoteAreaDesc] = QuoteNote.Description,
            [QuoteNoteNumber] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Quote.QuoteID ORDER BY QuoteNote.QuoteNoteID)
    FROM    Quote
            INNER JOIN QuoteNote
                ON QuoteNote.QuoteID = Quote.QuoteID
)
SELECT  q1.QuoteID,
        [Note1] = q1.Note,
        [Note2] = q2.Note,
        [Note3] = q3.Note,
        [NoteAreaID1] = q1.NoteAreaID,
        [NoteAreaID2] = q2.NoteAreaID,
        [NoteAreaID3] = q3.NoteAreaID,
        [NoteAreaDesc1] = q1.NoteAreaDesc,
        [NoteAreaDesc2] = q2.NoteAreaDesc,
        [NoteAreaDesc3] = q3.NoteAreaDesc
FROM    QuoteNotes q1
        LEFT JOIN QuoteNotes q2
            ON q1.QuoteID = q2.QuoteID
            AND q2.QuoteNoteNumber = 2
        LEFT JOIN QuoteNotes q3
            ON q1.QuoteID = q3.QuoteID
            AND q3.QuoteNoteNumber = 3 -- changed this to be 3
WHERE   q1.QuoteNoteNumber = 1;
```

Both should yield the same results, but one may perform better than the other.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/177a7/4)**

Comment: Didn't even cross my mind to have a temp table and 3 instances, thanks