# Issue in Convert row into column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a table- EmployeeDetails. In which we have two columns :- ColumnName and Details. Below is the table:-

```
ColumnNames     Details
-----------     -------
Sno             1
Firstname       Daya
Lastname        Sharma
EmailId         <email1>@gmail.com
sno             2
Firstname       Kriti 
Lastname        joshi
EmailId         <email2>@yahoo.com
```

Now I need to convert firstname, lastname, emailed and sno in columns. How we can do this?

And I want to convert into Column Name as

```
Sno  FirstName  Lastname  Emailid
1    Daya       Sharma    <email1>@gmail.com
2    Kriti      Joshi     <email2>@yahoo.com
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL or something else?

Comment: You can try with PIVOT like this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117955/making-row-values-into-column-values-sql-pivot

Comment: You need to use SQL Transpose command. 
Look this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql

Comment: and of many many others: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pivot+sql

Comment: @VANDANA PANDEY : should not use original mail ids , just a suggestion , might cause the spam flow

Comment: You can use dynamic sql with a cursor to loop trough table.

Comment: @jpw Sql server 2012 me using...

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari I have used pivot but not working. B'coz of aggregate function which I have to use in pivot it result only one record... Please try from ur end nd then let me know...

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid thnx for suggestion.

Comment: You **have to have** at least one more column (let's call it `EmployeeID`) to be able to properly pivot your data. Otherwise there is no way to tell which last name belongs to which first name, son, emailid etc.

Comment: @Vijaykumar This query is gud but resulting only one record as you have used 'max' aggregate function.

Comment: @peterm K in place of Sno if i'l take EmployeeID then is there any other way..

Answer (score 0):

```
select sno,firstname,lastname,Emailid
from
(
select columnnames,details from table
)d

pivot
(
max(details)
for columnnames in([sno],[firstname],[lastname],[emailid])
)piv;
```

Comment: Please always provide explanations. Code only answers are being frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer below link for the answer. Same question has been posted at below link :

[Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Hiii I have seen that example. They used max in it which resulting one record. But I want all records.

Answer (score 0):

You **have to have** at least one more column (let's call it EmployeeID) to be able to properly pivot your data. Otherwise there is no way to tell which last name belongs to which first name, Son, emailid etc

If you were to have such a column then `PIVOT` would work as expected

```
SELECT Sno, Firstname, Lastname, Emailid
  FROM
(
  SELECT EmployeeId, ColumnNames, Details 
    FROM EmployeeDetails
) s
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Details)
  FOR ColumnNames IN([Sno],[Firstname],[Lastname],[Emailid])
) p;
```

Output:

```
| SNO | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |            EMAILID |
|-----|-----------|----------|--------------------|
|   1 |      Daya |   Sharma | @gmail.com |
|   2 |     Kriti |    joshi | @yahoo.com |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3952b/3)** demo